# Elegant way of using AWK

Tags: parsing, unix, awk

I have a file that has field separated by multiple characters. For Ex:

```
abc sometext def;ghi=123; 
abc sometext def;ghi=123; 
abc sometext def;ghi=123;
```

Now I want to parse the file in AWK to extract the fields. for example to get all the values of 'ghi',

```
awk '{print $3}' | awk 'BEGIN {FS = "="} { print $NF }' inputFile.txt
```

Is there any way to parse the file in one shot instead of using multiple pipes and AWK commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be accomplished using multiple field separators in `awk`:

```
$ awk -F"[=;]" '{print $3}' file
123
123
123
```

This tells `awk` to use field separators `=` or `;`. Based on that, the numbers you want are in the 3rd position.

If you expect the `ghi` part to be changeable and important, you can also use `grep` with a look-behind:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=ghi=)\d+' file
123
123
123
```

This will print all digits after `ghi=`.

Comment: His example does not remove the `;`.  Other way to have multiple separators `awk -F"=|;" '{print $3}' file`

Comment: Yes, @Jotne, but I guess it is something good to be achieve. And I like this `-F"=|;"`, looks neat when there are just a couple of separators.

Comment: And you can have word as separators with the `|` like `-F"before|after"`

Comment: Wow, that is new for me. Then, you can even do `awk -F'ghi=' '{print $2}' file` for this question's purpose.

Comment: Yes, that will work fine. And if you do not like the `;`, you can use `-F"ghi=|;"`

Comment: @Jotne I come back to this comments because I was just told about `-F` multiple separators by Ed Morton. See, it is a very good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981592/bash-oneliner-with-awk-runs-in-terminal-but-not-in-script/19981642#comment29762646_19981642

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `split` function in `awk`

```
awk '{split($3,a,"=");print a[2]}'
123;
123;
123;
```

This divides filed nr `3` using `=` as separator in to an array `a`, then print second value of array `a[2]`

---

If there are variation of fields in filed number 3 and you like the last, do like this:

```
awk '{n=split($3,a,"=");print a[n]}'
123;
123;
123;
```

---

In your case, this will do too:

```
awk -F= '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Thanks. This way of parsing seems to be easy and elegant.