# Bash oneliner with AWK runs in terminal but not in script

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I have a file with the following type of data:

```
4-11-11 12:59:01,C,26,668
4-11-11 12:59:31,C,26,668
4-11-11 13:00:01,C,26,668
4-11-11 13:00:31,C,26,668
4-11-11 13:01:01,C,26,668
4-11-11 13:01:31,C,26,668
```

and I want the following output:

```
12:59:01 26.668
12:59:31 26.668
13:00:01 26.668
13:00:31 26.668
13:01:01 26.668
13:01:31 26.668
```

This works just fine in the termal with the following line, but not in a bash script, it just gives me an empty file. The problem started after I added the awk part.

```
cut -d ' ' -f2 $file | cut -d ',' -f-1,3- | awk -f tmp.csv -F"," '{print $1 " " $2 "." $3}' | sed 's/"//'  > tmp.csv
cp tmp.csv > $file
```

Could anyone explain why this won't work in a script?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use tmp.csv as script file to awk and as output of commands? Because this is what you are asking awk/sed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this `awk` it can be easier:

```
$ awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $2, $4"."$5}' file
12:59:01 26.668
12:59:31 26.668
13:00:01 26.668
13:00:31 26.668
13:01:01 26.668
13:01:31 26.668
```

- `-F'[ ,]'` sets two possible delimiters: space and comma.
- `print $2, $4"."$5` prints the 2nd, 4th and 5th fields based on those delimiters.

Regarding why your script did not work, it is just because you added `-f tmp.csv` unnecessarily.

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f2 a | cut -d ',' -f-1,3- | awk -F"," '{print $1 " " $2 "." $3}' | sed 's/"//'
12:59:01 26.668
12:59:31 26.668
13:00:01 26.668
13:00:31 26.668
13:01:01 26.668
13:01:31 26.668
```

Also you use `-f tmp.csv` and then `>  tmp.csv` which does not make sense. Note a file cannot be used as stdin and stdout at the same time.

Comment: This works great, thanks!
Out of curiosity (and to avoid future problems) I'd still like to know why my solution didn't work in a script, any idea?

Comment: @Xizam just updated accordingly. With a little change (deleting the `-f file`) works to me. See the update.

Comment: The -f tmp.csv was not actually in the code I was trying to run in the script, that was sloppy copying done by me. The actual problem lied in the fact that I was stupid enough to use "for file in *.csv" and saving the output to tmp.csv. I did not yet overwrite my original files with tmp.csv so I wouldn't have to keep copying them back if the script didnt work. So that tmp.csv file got overwritten as the last step, giving me an empty file.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad it was just this, it is such a common error, so don't blame yourself :)

Comment: `-F" |,"` should be just the character set `-F'[ ,]'`.

Comment: What's the difference between the two ways, @EdMorton?

Comment: The first form is an or-separated list of REs, the second is a set of characters. You don't actually want/need to use an or-separated list of REs, you simply want to use a set of characters so just specify that using the appropriate language constructs. Functionally they will behave the same with those 2 specific characters, but it would matter if, say, a period or question mark or any other RE metacharacter was needed as an additional field separator. The first form also starts to look silly if you build on it, e.g. "a|b|c|d" vs "[abcd]", which is another sign it's not the right approach.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks @EdMorton. I will use then `-F'[a,b]' for many cases and just use for example `-F'hello|bye'` for other edge cases.

Comment: Sounds good, as long as it's clear that `[a,b]` means `a` or `,` or `b`. If you wanted only `a` or `b` then that'd just be `[ab]`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your surroundings in the script are to blame, but the whole thing can be done using just `read`:

```
while IFS=' ,' read a b c d e
do
  echo "$b $d.$e"
done < inputfile
```

Maybe this solves the issue on a different level ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't copying the temp file; you are just erasing your original file. I'm not sure why you aren't getting an error (you should be, because `cp` expects two arguments).

Instead of

```
cp tmp.csh > $file
```

use

```
cp tmp.csv "$file"
```

Comment: Right.  Didn't even notice that.  But I have the feeling that the error you found here is just in the question, not in the script the OP is actually using (copy/paste error).